# Why can I put a NSNumber inside a NSString and not get a exception?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, types

I develop in objective-c for a couple years now, but never faced something like this. I'd like to know if someone have an explanation why this is possible, look:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.23413];
NSDictionary *dicTest = @{ @"number": number };
NSString *string = [dicTest valueForKey:@"number"];

NSLog(@"Is string? %d", [string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]);
NSLog(@"Is number? %d", [string isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]);
```

The debugger says that the type of the variable is:

```
string  __NSCFNumber *  (double)1.23413 0x000060c000222ae0
```

How this is possible at runtime without crashing? Objective C isn't suposed to be typed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't strongly enforce types in the way you expect.

The return type of `valueForKey:` is `id`, which means “object identifier”. The `id` type can reference an instance of any class and can be converted to a pointer to any specific class without any checking. You won't get an error unless you send an unrecognized message to the instance. For example, this statement:

```
NSLog(@"length = %ld", (long)string.length);
```

triggers this run-time error:

```
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100404230
```

You can enforce stronger typing sometimes using “lightweight generics”. However, you first need to understand that you should not generally be using `valueForKey:`. The `valueForKey:` message is part of “key-value coding” (KVC) and is a way to access an object's properties by name at runtime. You should instead use `objectForKey:` on a dictionary (`[dicTest objectForKey:@"number"]`) or just use subscripting directly (`dicTest[@"number"]`).

Okay, so let's say you mend your ways and use `objectForKey` instead. Then, if all the values in the dictionary will be `NSNumber *`, you can declare your dictionary like this:

```
NSDictionary<NSString *, NSNumber *> *dicTest = @{ @"number": number };
```

Then you'll get a warning if you assume a different type for a value extracted from the dictionary:

```
NSString *string = [dicTest objectForKey:@"number"];
// warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSString *' with an expression of type 'NSNumber * _Nullable' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *string = [dicTest valueForKey:@"number"];
```

You're essentially "casting" the result of the dictionary lookup to be an NSString. There's no check that the result of the dictionary lookup is *actually* an NSString.

```
string  __NSCFNumber *  (double)1.23413 0x000060c000222ae0
```

The debugger shows that your variable `string` is actually an NSNumber, not an NSString.

> How this is possible at runtime without crashing?

There's nothing illegal about declaring a an object as a completely unrelated Type. You only run into trouble when you send an invalid message that the object is unable to interpret.

For example both NSNumber and NSString have the property `boolValue`.

```
@property(readonly) BOOL boolValue;
```

So if you send `boolValue` to your "NSString", the true NSNumber object will still respond to that message. No Exception.

But if you use a String-specific method/property that ONLY NSString implements, the true NSNumber object will not be able to respond. This causes the Exception.